# SwiftUI animation not working when embedded inside another view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, swift5

I made a reusable circular progress bar. I applied `repeatForever` animation to keep it rotating but it only works when used directly with a @State or @Published variable and doesn't work when it is embedded in another view.

> Reusable RingView. Which is a circular progress bar

```
struct RingView: View {
    private let percent: CGFloat = 80   // Keeping it fixed 80 for test purpose
    var color = Color.primaryLightColor // Some random color
    @Binding var show: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { bounds in

                Circle()
                    .trim(from: self.show ? self.progress : 1, to: 1)
                    .stroke(
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [self.color]), startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading),
                        style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth(width: bounds.size.width), lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: .infinity, dash: [20, 0], dashPhase: 0)
                )
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                    .animation(.none)
                    .frame(width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            }
        }
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(show ? 360.0 : 0.0))
        .animation(show ? Animation.linear(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) : .none)
    }

    func multiplier(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        width / 44
    }

    func lineWidth(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        5 * self.multiplier(width: width)
    }

    var progress: CGFloat {
        1 - (percent / 100)
    }
}
```

> Progress Button. It uses the RingView above. A general use case is to show animation when doing a long background task.
>
> **The RingView animation doesn't work in this ProgressButton**

```
struct ProgressButton: View {
        var action: () -> Void
        var image: Image? = nil
        var text: String = ""
        var backgroundColor: Color = Color.blue
        var textColor: Color = .white
        @Binding var showProgress: Bool

        var body: some View {
            Button(action: action) {
                HStack {
                    if showProgress {
                        RingView(color: textColor, show: self.$showProgress)
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .transition(.scale)
                            .animation(.Spring())
                    } else {
                        image?
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    }
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(textColor)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, alignment: .center)
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
```

> When RingView animation works. When I use it directly as below.

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var showProgress = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // WORKING
            RingView(show: self.$showProgress)
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)

            // NOT WORKING
            ProgressButton(action: {
                self.showProgress = true
            }, image: Image("password-lock"), text: "Login", backgroundColor: .blue, showProgress: self.showProgress)
        }
    }
}
```

---

> I think I'm doing some mistake understanding how @Binding and @State are working.

Comment: i tried to reproduce your "working" case with loginview -> but it didnt work...maybe you can recheck your example or even better: make it reproducible AND compilable...thank you

Comment: @Chris I've got the answer but have edited my code and have removed custom strings and variables in this might help someone. Thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animation is activate on state **change**. In provided code there is no change so no animation at all.

Below are main changes so I made it work. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 (with some replication of absent custom dependencies)

[image: demo]

1. Made initial animation off

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var showProgress = false

// ... other code

    // no model provided so used same state for progress
    ProgressButton(action: {
        self.showProgress.toggle()     // << activate change !!!
    }, image: Image("password-lock"), text: L.Login.LoginSecurely, backgroundColor: self.isLoginButtonEnabled ? Color.primaryLightColor : Color.gray, showProgress: $showProgress)
```

2. Add internal ring activating state inside progress button; same state used for hide/unhide and activating does not work, again, because when ring appeared there is no change (it is already true) so ring is not activated

   @State private var actiavteRing = false     // << here !!
   var body: some View {
   Button(action: action) {
   HStack {

   ```
            if showProgress {
                RingView(color: textColor, show: self.$actiavteRing) // !!
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .animation(.spring())
                    .onAppear { self.actiavteRing = true } // << 
                    .onDisappear { self.actiavteRing = false } // <<
   ```
3. in Ring fixed animation deactivation to avoid cumulative effect (.none does not work here), so

   .rotationEffect(.degrees(show ? 360.0 : 0.0))
   .animation(show ? Animation.linear(duration:
   1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) : .default)   // << here !!

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I am still confused with this part: Why didn't it worked when I used `@Binding showProgress` from `ProgressButton` with `RingView's` `show` variable. Does it not pass state changes from `Login` to `ProgressButton` and then to `RingView` ?

Comment: @harsh_v, it is passed, but at the moment when RingView appears it is initiated with already true value, so there is no trigger to activate animation.