# SwiftUI: How do I keep the animation on hiding and showing a button (view)?

Tags: animation, swiftui

In my application, I have a button, the animation of which indicates that the application is currently executing the function associated with this button.

Everything works fine until it becomes necessary to hide / show the button (or the view that contains it) on the screen.
When the button returns to the screen, the button animation stops working. I understand why this is happening (there is no state change that needs to be animated), but I do not understand how it is easy to solve ((

Ultimately, I want the button animation to always depend only on the state that the animation displays, no matter how many times the button is hidden / shown.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var animationOn = false
@State private var showButton = true

let buttonAnimation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        Toggle("Show button", isOn: $showButton)
            .padding()
        
        if showButton {
            
            Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: animationOn ? 5 : 0)
                        .scaleEffect(animationOn ? 2 : 1)
                        .opacity(animationOn ? 0 : 1)
                        .animation(animationOn ? buttonAnimation : Animation.default)
                )
                .onTapGesture {
                    animationOn.toggle()
                }

        }
        
        Text("animation is \(animationOn ? "on" : "off")")
            .padding()
        
    }
    
}
```

}

[showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8kyF.gif)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62072209/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself ))
The point, as I already wrote, is that a change is needed leading to an animation when the button appears on the screen.
The required actions are noted in the comments in the code.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var animationOn = false
@State private var showButton = true

let buttonAnimation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)

//1. declare properties for animation
@State private var lineWithForAnimation: CGFloat = 2
@State private var scaleEffectForAnimation: CGFloat = 2
@State private var opacityForAnimation: Double = 0

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        Toggle("Show button", isOn: $showButton)
            .padding()
        
        if showButton {
            
            Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        //2. use properties for animation
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: lineWithForAnimation)
                        .scaleEffect(scaleEffectForAnimation)
                        .opacity(opacityForAnimation)
                        .animation(animationOn ? buttonAnimation : Animation.default)
                )
                .onTapGesture {
                    animationOn.toggle()
                    changeAnimatedProperties()
                }
                //3. change properties for animation onAppear
                .onAppear{
                    changeAnimatedProperties()
                }
                //4. reset properties for animation onDisappear
                .onDisappear{
                    resetAnimatedProperties()
                }

        }
        
        Text("animation is \(animationOn ? "on" : "off")")
            .padding()
        
    }
    
}

func changeAnimatedProperties() {
    lineWithForAnimation = animationOn ? 2 : 0
    scaleEffectForAnimation = animationOn ? 2 : 1
    opacityForAnimation = animationOn ? 0 : 1
}

func resetAnimatedProperties() {
    lineWithForAnimation = 0
    scaleEffectForAnimation = 1
    opacityForAnimation = 1
}
```

}